# Send instruccions to NV9 USB+ by android devide java D2xxManager

Tags: java, android, d2xx

I'm trying to communicate with NV9 USB+ device by an android app ( who search the usb device), I get the device by D2xxManager but I don't know how to send instructions to it, how can I send instructions and get de result of it ?

My android version is Android 11 and sdk is 33.

This is my code:

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static ITLDeviceCom deviceCom;
    private static D2xxManager ftD2xx = null;
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private static FT_Device ftDev = null;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_STORAGE = 0;
    private final long  SSP_KEY = 0123456701234567L;

    BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Starting onReceive");
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {
                // never come here(when attached, go to onNewIntent)
                System.out.println("ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED");
                openDevice();
            } else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
                System.out.println("ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED");
                closeDevice();
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Ending onReceive");
        }
    };


    @SuppressLint("UnspecifiedRegisterReceiverFlag")
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.i(TAG, "Starting onCreate");

        UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) this.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

        // Obtener una lista de dispositivos USB conectados
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = usbManager.getDeviceList();

        for (UsbDevice device : deviceList.values()) {

            String deviceName = device.getDeviceName();
            String serial = device.getSerialNumber();
            int productId = device.getProductId();
            int vendorId = device.getVendorId();
            String manufacturerName = device.getManufacturerName();

            Log.i(TAG,"Device name: " + deviceName + " | Product id: " + productId + " | Vendor id: " + vendorId + " | Serial number: " + serial + " | Manufacturer Name: " + manufacturerName);
        }

        try {
            ftD2xx = D2xxManager.getInstance(this);
            Log.i(TAG, "Setting VID and PID");
            ftD2xx.setVIDPID(0x191c, 0x4104);

        } catch (D2xxManager.D2xxException ex) {
            Log.e("SSP FTmanager", ex.toString());
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "Inicilice registerReceiver");
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
        filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);
        filter.setPriority(500);
        this.registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);

        deviceCom = new ITLDeviceCom();

        openDevice();

        if (ftDev != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "ftDev != null => Calling to setup and start");
            deviceCom.setup(ftDev, 0, false, false, SSP_KEY);
            deviceCom.start();

            Log.i(TAG, "Escrow mode => true");
            deviceCom.SetEscrowMode(true);
            Log.i(TAG, "Device mode => true");
            deviceCom.SetDeviceEnable(true);
            Log.i(TAG, "Escrow action => Accept");
            deviceCom.SetEscrowAction(SSPSystem.BillAction.Accept);
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "Ending onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting onDestroy");
        this.unregisterReceiver(mUsbReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    /**********   USB functions   ******************************************/
    private void openDevice() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting openDevice");
        if (ftDev != null && ftDev.isOpen()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "if the device is connected and open, we restart the thread task");
            SetConfig(9600, (byte) 8, (byte) 2, (byte) 0, (byte) 0);
            ftDev.purge((byte) (D2xxManager.FT_PURGE_TX | D2xxManager.FT_PURGE_RX));
            ftDev.restartInTask();
            return;
        }

        int devCount = 0;

        if (ftD2xx != null) {
            // Get the connected USB FTDI devices
            devCount = ftD2xx.createDeviceInfoList(this);
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "ftD2xx == null");
            return;
        }

        D2xxManager.FtDeviceInfoListNode[] deviceList = new D2xxManager.FtDeviceInfoListNode[devCount];
        ftD2xx.getDeviceInfoList(devCount, deviceList);
      
        if (devCount <= 0) {
            System.out.println("none detected devices");
            Log.w(TAG, "devCount <= 0");
            return;
        }

        if (ftDev == null) {
            System.out.println("ftDev is null, getting position  " + (devCount - 1));
            ftDev = ftD2xx.openByIndex(this, devCount -1);
        } else {
            synchronized (ftDev) {
                System.out.println("ftDev is NOT null, synchronicing position " + (devCount - 1));
                ftDev = ftD2xx.openByIndex(this, devCount -1);
            }
        }

        // run thread
        if (ftDev.isOpen()) {
            SetConfig(9600, (byte) 8, (byte) 2, (byte) 0, (byte) 0);
            ftDev.purge((byte) (D2xxManager.FT_PURGE_TX | D2xxManager.FT_PURGE_RX));
            ftDev.restartInTask();
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Ending openDevice");
    }

    private static void closeDevice() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting closeDevice");
        if (ftDev != null) {
            deviceCom.Stop();
            ftDev.close();
            Log.i(TAG, "Device closed");
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Ending closeDevice");
    }

    public static void SetConfig(int baud, byte dataBits, byte stopBits, byte parity, byte flowControl) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting SetConfig");
        if (!ftDev.isOpen()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Starting SetConfig");
            return;
        }

        // configure our port
        // reset to UART mode for 232 devices
        ftDev.setBitMode((byte) 0, D2xxManager.FT_BITMODE_RESET);
        ftDev.setBaudRate(baud);

        switch (dataBits) {
            case 7:
                dataBits = D2xxManager.FT_DATA_BITS_7;
                break;
            case 8:
                dataBits = D2xxManager.FT_DATA_BITS_8;
                break;
            default:
                dataBits = D2xxManager.FT_DATA_BITS_8;
                break;
        }

        switch (stopBits) {
            case 1:
                stopBits = D2xxManager.FT_STOP_BITS_1;
                break;
            case 2:
                stopBits = D2xxManager.FT_STOP_BITS_2;
                break;
                default:
                    stopBits = D2xxManager.FT_STOP_BITS_1;
                    break;
        }

        switch (parity) {
            case 0:
                parity = D2xxManager.FT_PARITY_NONE;
                break;
            case 1:
                parity = D2xxManager.FT_PARITY_ODD;
                break;
            case 2:
                parity = D2xxManager.FT_PARITY_EVEN;
                break;
            case 3:
                parity = D2xxManager.FT_PARITY_MARK;
                break;
            case 4:
                parity = D2xxManager.FT_PARITY_SPACE;
                break;
            default:
                parity = D2xxManager.FT_PARITY_NONE;
                break;
        }

        ftDev.setDataCharacteristics(dataBits, stopBits, parity);

        short flowCtrlSetting;
        switch (flowControl) {
            case 0:
                flowCtrlSetting = D2xxManager.FT_FLOW_NONE;
                break;
            case 1:
                flowCtrlSetting = D2xxManager.FT_FLOW_RTS_CTS;
                break;
            case 2:
                flowCtrlSetting = D2xxManager.FT_FLOW_DTR_DSR;
                break;
            case 3:
                flowCtrlSetting = D2xxManager.FT_FLOW_XON_XOFF;
                break;
            default:
                flowCtrlSetting = D2xxManager.FT_FLOW_NONE;
                break;
        }

        ftDev.setFlowControl(flowCtrlSetting, (byte) 0x0b, (byte) 0x0d);
        Log.i(TAG, "Ending SetConfig");
    }

    public static void DisplaySetUp(SSPDevice dev)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting DisplaySetUp");

        // check for type comapable
        if(dev.type != SSPDeviceType.BillValidator){
            return;
        }
        /* device details  */
        System.out.println(" " + dev.firmwareVersion);
        System.out.println(" " + dev.headerType.toString());
        System.out.println(" " + dev.serialNumber);
        System.out.println(" " + dev.datasetVersion);

        /* display the channel info */
        for (ItlCurrency itlCurrency : dev.currency) {
            @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") String v = itlCurrency.country + " " + String.format("%.2f", itlCurrency.realvalue);
            System.out.println(v);
        }

        // if device has barcode hardware
        if (dev.barCodeReader.hardWareConfig != SSPDevice.BarCodeStatus.None) {
            // send new configuration
            BarCodeReader cfg = new BarCodeReader();
            cfg.barcodeReadEnabled = true;
            cfg.billReadEnabled = true;
            cfg.numberOfCharacters = 18;
            cfg.format = SSPDevice.BarCodeFormat.Interleaved2of5;
            cfg.enabledConfig = SSPDevice.BarCodeStatus.Both;
            deviceCom.SetBarcocdeConfig(cfg);
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Ending DisplaySetUp");
    }

    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    public static void DisplayEvents(DeviceEvent ev) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting DisplayEvents");
        switch (ev.event) {
            case CommunicationsFailure:
                System.out.println("CommunicationsFailure");
                break;
            case Ready:
                System.out.println("Ready");
                break;
            case BillRead:
                System.out.println("Reading");
                break;
            case BillEscrow:
                System.out.println("Bill Escrow: " + ev.currency + " " +  String.format("%.2f", ev.value));
                break;
            case BillStacked:
                System.out.println("BillStacked");
                break;
            case BillReject:
                System.out.println("Bill Reject");
                break;
            case BillJammed:
                System.out.println("Bill jammed");
                break;
            case BillFraud:
                System.out.println("Bill Fraud: " + ev.currency + " " +  String.format("%.2f", ev.value));
                break;
            case BillCredit:
                System.out.println("Bill Credit: " + ev.currency + " " +  String.format("%.2f", ev.value));
                break;
            case Full:
                System.out.println("Bill Cashbox full");
                break;
            case Initialising:
                System.out.println("Initialising");
                break;
            case Disabled:
                System.out.println("Disabled");
                break;
            case SoftwareError:
                System.out.println("Software error");
                break;
            case AllDisabled:
                System.out.println("All channels disabled");
                break;
            case CashboxRemoved:
                System.out.println("Cashbox removed");
                break;
            case CashboxReplaced:
                System.out.println("Cashbox replaced");
                break;
            case NotePathOpen:
                System.out.println("Note path open");
                break;
            case BarCodeTicketEscrow:
                System.out.println("Barcode ticket escrow:");
                break;
            case BarCodeTicketStacked:
                System.out.println("Barcode ticket stacked");
                break;
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Ending DisplayEvents");
    }

    
    }
```

**ITLDeviceCom**

```
public class ITLDeviceCom extends Thread implements DeviceSetupListener, DeviceEventListener, DeviceFileUpdateListener {

    private static boolean isrunning = false;
    private static SSPSystem sspSystem;
    private FT_Device ftDev = null;
    static final int READBUF_SIZE = 256;
    static final int WRITEBUF_SIZE = 4096;
    byte[] rbuf = new byte[READBUF_SIZE];
    byte[] wbuf = new byte[WRITEBUF_SIZE];
    int mReadSize = 0;
    private SSPDevice sspDevice = null;


    public ITLDeviceCom(){

        sspSystem = new SSPSystem();

        sspSystem.setOnDeviceSetupListener(this);
        sspSystem.setOnEventUpdateListener(this);
        sspSystem.setOnDeviceFileUpdateListener(this);

    }

    public void setup(FT_Device ftdev, int address, boolean escrow, boolean essp, long key){

        ftDev = ftdev;
        /** void SetAddress(int address)
         *  Description: Sets the SSP address for the device to connect to.
         *  Parameters: [address: the address of the device (0x00 – 0x7E)].
         *  Default: the address is set to 0x00
         * */
        sspSystem.SetAddress(address);

        /** void EscrowMode(boolean mode)
         *  Description: Enables or disables escrow mode for bill acceptance.
         *  Parameters: [mode: true to enable escrow mode, false to disable].
         *  Default: The object will be set to escrow disabled at start-up
         * */
        sspSystem.EscrowMode(escrow); // enable for escrow mode

        /** void SetESSPMode
         *  Description: sets the object eSSP mode state.
         *  Parameters: [Boolean mode: true –> enable eSSP, false -> disable eSSP, long key -> the eSSP fixed key for the device e.g 0x0123456701234567].
         *  Default: eSSP disabled.
         * */
        sspSystem.SetESSPMode(essp, key);

        sspSystem.SetBillEscrowAction(SSPSystem.BillAction.Accept);

    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        long startTimeRead = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        long timeOutTime = 10000;


        int readSize = 0;
        sspSystem.Run();

        isrunning = true;
        while(isrunning){

            synchronized (ftDev) {

                // poll for transmit data
                int newdatalen = sspSystem.GetNewData(wbuf);
                if (newdatalen > 0) {
                    if(sspSystem.GetDownloadState() != SSPSystem.DownloadSetupState.active) {
                        ftDev.purge((byte) 1);
                    }
                    ftDev.write(wbuf, newdatalen);
                    sspSystem.SetComsBufferWritten(true);
                }
                // poll for received
                readSize = ftDev.getQueueStatus();
                if (readSize > 0) {
                    mReadSize = readSize;
                    if (mReadSize > READBUF_SIZE) {
                        mReadSize = READBUF_SIZE;
                    }
                    readSize = ftDev.read(rbuf,mReadSize );
                    sspSystem.ProcessResponse(rbuf, readSize);
                }

            }// end of synchronized

            // coms config changes
            final SSPComsConfig cfg = sspSystem.GetComsConfig();
            if(cfg.configUpdate == SSPComsConfig.ComsConfigChangeState.ccNewConfig){
                cfg.configUpdate = SSPComsConfig.ComsConfigChangeState.ccUpdating;

               MainActivity.SetConfig(cfg.baud,cfg.dataBits,cfg.stopBits,cfg.parity,cfg.flowControl);

                cfg.configUpdate = SSPComsConfig.ComsConfigChangeState.ccUpdated;
            }


            try {
                sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void OnNewDeviceSetup(SSPDevice dev) {
        // set local device object
        Log.i(TAG, "OnNewDeviceSetup");
        sspDevice = dev;
        // call to Main UI
         MainActivity.DisplaySetUp(dev);
    }

    @Override
    public void OnDeviceDisconnect(final SSPDevice dev) {   Log.i(TAG, "OnDeviceDisconnect");  }

    @Override
    public void OnDeviceEvent(final DeviceEvent ev) { MainActivity.DisplayEvents(ev); }


    void Stop()
    {
        sspSystem.Close();
        isrunning = false;
    }

    void SetEscrowMode(boolean mode){ if(sspSystem != null) sspSystem.EscrowMode(mode); }

    void SetDeviceEnable(boolean en) {
        if (sspSystem != null) {
            if (en) {
                sspSystem.EnableDevice();
            }else {
                sspSystem.DisableDevice();
            }
        }
    }

    void SetEscrowAction(SSPSystem.BillAction action){ if(sspSystem != null) sspSystem.SetBillEscrowAction(action); }

    void SetBarcocdeConfig(BarCodeReader cfg) { if(sspSystem != null) sspSystem.SetBarCodeConfiguration(cfg); }

    int GetDeviceCode()
    {
        if(sspSystem != null){
            return sspDevice.headerType.getValue();
        }else{
            return -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void OnFileUpdateStatus(SSPUpdate sspUpdate) {

    }
}
```